# How to use Apache UIMA RUTA with UIMA DUCC?

Tags: uima, ruta

How to use Apache UIMA RUTA with UIMA DUCC? Is there any reference or an example for the same to test it?

Comment: There is no reference example yet. Did you hit any problems (as Ruta is just an analysis engine)?

Comment: Nope :( unfortunately.